# how to make a python package with numpy, pandas, scipy, sklearn inside?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I want to make a python package with numpy, pandas, scipy and sklearn, so I can take it to any linux without install python, but i came across this:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data1/sigmoidguo/TOOLS/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/data1/sigmoidguo/TOOLS/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/data1/sigmoidguo/TOOLS/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/data1/sigmoidguo/TOOLS/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/data1/sigmoidguo/TOOLS/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it without root permission?

PS: I don't have root permission, so I can't install python site-packages to python...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). It is a multi-platform python distribution that can be installed in your home folder (with user rights). It comes with `pip` and `conda` commands to install any package you need. It already comes with all the packages you mention (`numpy`, `pandas`, `scipy` and `sklearn`), so sounds like a good fit for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Would http://python-xy.github.io/ do the trick?

(if it was windows I would suggest the portable http://winpython.sourceforge.net/)